# grouping character variables in R

Tags: r

I want to make a dataframe that show incidences of character variables grouped by one variable, in this case c2_inicio.
I have data like:

```
     c2_inicio usuario_inicia          f_alarm
1  C2 Poniente       PH903731            DELITO
2     C2 Norte       C4895756          SERVICIO
3   C2 Oriente        Sistema      FALSA ALARMA
4  C2 Poniente        Sistema      FALSA ALARMA
5     C2 Norte       C4895646          SERVICIO
6    C2 Centro       C4895678 URGENCIAS MEDICAS
7   C2 Oriente       C5PEPK86        EMERGENCIA
8  C2 Poniente       C5ROGK95      FALTA CÍVICA
9  C2 Poniente        Sistema      FALSA ALARMA
10 C2 Poniente        Sistema      FALSA ALARMA
```

and I need a table like this:

```
  c2_inicio   incidence_user    incidence_DELITO   incidence_EMERGENCY
1 C2 Centro        38582       [number of DELITOS] [number of EMERGENCIES]
2 C2 Norte         76632       [...by c2_inicio]
3 C2 Oriente       77075
4 C2 Poniente      72333
5 C2 Sur           59137
6 C4i                 65
```

I tried:

```
base_c2 <- c4%>%group_by(c2_inicio)%>%summarise(incidentes=n())
```

but only counts the total number of observations per c2_inicio.

How can i achieve that? Thx in advanced ;)

Comment: What is the `incidence_user` in the expected output.  Is it the frequency?

Comment: Yes. in tjhis case the number of users that feed the database

Comment: It is not clear what is `DELITOS` and `EMERGENCY`.  Is that an exact match in the second column or substring?  Try `c4%>%group_by(c2_inicio)%>%summarise(incidentes_user=n(, incidence_DELITO = sum(f_alarm == "DELITO"), incidence_EMERGENCY = sum(f_alarm == "EMERGENCY"))`

Comment: i recieve this error:Error in summarise_impl(.data, dots) : `n()` does not take arguments    }

Comment: There's a typo in @akrun's comment, I've fixed it here: `c4 %>% group_by(c2_inicio) %>% summarise(incidentes_user=n(), incidence_DELITO = sum(f_alarm == "DELITO"), incidence_EMERGENCY = sum(f_alarm == "EMERGENCY"))`